# yum + what is the message - No package ansible available

Tags: linux, ansible, yum

I am try to install the ansible tool on my linux red-hat version - 5.7

```
yum install ansible
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
No package ansible available.
Nothing to do
```

ansible isnt installed on my linux machine - for sure!

so why I get - No package ansible available. and how to resolve this?

the view from yum.repos.d is:

```
/etc/yum.repos.d]# ls
rhel-debuginfo.repo  rhel-source.repo  service-cd-repo.repo  stp-default-   repo.repo
```

I have resolving as the following:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=63.4 ms
```

Update - try to install epel-release package

```
yum install epel-release
Loaded plugins: security
service-cd                                                                                                      |  951 B     00:00     
swp-default                                                                                                  |  951 B     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
No package epel-release available.
Nothing to do
```

**second update:**

```
  wget --no-check-certificate https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel- release-latest-5.noarch.rpm
 --2015-08-17 14:54:20--  https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-   release-latest-5.noarch.rpm
  Resolving dl.fedoraproject.org... 209.132.181.26, 209.132.181.27,   209.132.181.25, ...
  Connecting to dl.fedoraproject.org|209.132.181.26|:443... connected.
 WARNING: cannot verify dl.fedoraproject.org's certificate, issued by     `/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Hig:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
  Length: 12232 (12K) [application/x-rpm]
  Saving to: `epel-release-latest-5.noarch.rpm'

  100%  [==========================================================================================>] 12,232      54.0K/s   in 0.2s    

     2015-08-17 14:54:22 (54.0 KB/s) - `epel-release-latest-5.noarch.rpm.1' saved [12232/12232]


 rpm -ivh epel-release-latest-5.noarch.rpm
 warning: epel-release-latest-5.noarch.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature:  NOKEY, key ID 217521f6
 Preparing...                ###########################################   [100%]



  yum repolist
  Loaded plugins: security
  epel                                                                                                               | 3.7 kB     00:00     
   service-cd                                                                                                      |  951 B     00:00     
 swp-default                                                                                                   |  951 B     00:00     
repo id                                       repo name                                                                          status
epel                                          Extra Packages for      Enterprise Linux 5 - i386                                    5,411
service-cd                                    RHEL5 service-cd repository                                                         155
 swp-default                                   RHEL5 yum repository                                                                 239
  repolist: 5,805



 yum install ansible
 Loaded plugins: security
 Setting up Install Process
 No package ansible available.
 Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 35):

Ansible is part of the *Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux* (EPEL) repository so you need to [install epel-release package](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) first

```
$ sudo yum install epel-release
```

The repo should now be visible in the repo list

```
$ sudo yum repolist
```

So now you can go ahead and install ansible

```
$ sudo yum install ansible
```

Before RHEL 7.x, the installtion needed to be done manually.
Open [install epel-release package](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) and download the newest version of *epel-release* for EL5 or follow the commands below

```
$ wget https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
$ sudo rpm –ivh epel-release-latest-5.noarch.rpm
$ sudo yum repolist
$ sudo yum install ansible
```

In the installation manual for ansible, this is referred to as [*configure EPEL*](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#latest-release-via-yum)

Hope this helps :)

#### Response to second update

When installing manually you may also need to expire your cache and recreate the the local repository database before you can install software from EPEL. That can be done with the following

```
$ yum clean expire-cache
$ yum createrepo
```

Comment: See my update I try to install the yum install epel-release - but I get the same status -:(

Comment: @maihabunash On older versions of RHEL, the package need to be downloaded and installed manually.

Comment: @maihabunash I've updated my answer to work with your version of RHEL

Comment: Hi  Söderström see my second update , still  we cant install the ansible -:(

Comment: @maihabunash I've updated my answer with respect to this. I have a vague memory about needing to expire and re-create the repository cache when doing manual installation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87171/discussion-between-maihabunash-and-rikard-soderstrom).

Comment: I also try it and still the same results -:(

Comment: In needed to first run `sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel` on AMZN Linux

Comment: RPM url is not valid anymore. It should be `https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm` or `https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm`

Comment: @Icarus Thank you for highligting the fact that fedora no longer supports EPEL 5. I am not sure that referring to a different version would be correct, since most of this has been referring to epel release 5, and from 7 and onwards manual install isn't required either. So I think it may be best to keep as is.

Comment: @RikardSöderström Sure, completely understandable, thank you for the explanation! In that case, would it not be worth to provide the current url for the desired RPM? It can be found in `https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm`

Comment: Execute following commans on AWS EC2 instance

1. sudo yum install -y epel-release ;  
2. sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel ;
3. sudo yum repolist ;
4. sudo yum install ansible ;

Answer (score 4):

EPEL is required for this.

Follow these steps for installing Ansible for Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7
Based on the redhat version, follow 
[Enabline EPEL](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/)

```
1. yum -y update
2. yum install wget
3. wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm
4. rpm -ivh epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm
5. yum repolist
6. yum install ansible
```

Comment: epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm is not available, instead try epel-release-7-12.noarch.rpm 
Dont forget to update 12 in next steps as well.

Comment: This is a no BS answer and worked like a charm. The only thing I want to change is, the file used in `wget` and `rpm -ivh ...` command, could be different name over time. I had to use `epel-release-7-13.noarch.rpm`

Comment: doing `yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm`  worked for me